# Rails includes associations with left join conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider these two associated models, `Program` and `SpentFinance`:

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :spent_finances
end

class SpentFinance < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Each spent finance has a `time_period_type`, such as `'year'` or `'month'`.

How can I retrieve all programs, and at the same time preload all associated `spent_finances` associated with a program that have a certain `time_period_type`?

Note:

- The query must retrieve ALL programs, including programs that do not have any spent finances of the requested time period type.
- Should provide a way to programmatically change the `time_period_type` in the query

---

These are the attempts I've made at cracking this problem.

**First attempt**

```
Program
.references(:spent_finances)
.includes(:spent_finances)
.merge(SpentFinance.where(time_period_type: time_period_type))
```

This doesn't work, because it filters out programs that don't have spent finances with the specified time period type. (It adds the time_period_type condition to the WHERE clause and not the JOIN ON clause.)

**Second attempt**

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :yearly_spent_finances,
    -> { where(time_period_type: 'year') },
    className: 'SpentFinance'
end

programs = Program.references(:yearly_spent_finances).includes(:yearly_spent_finances)

programs[0].yearly_spent_finances
```

This works (the last line does not execute another query), and indeed it is the [officially recommended solution](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations). However, it doesn't allow me to programmatically specify the desired `time_period_type`. For example, if I want to do a similar query as above, but change the time_period_type to `'month'`, then I would have to add another association `has_many :monthly_spent_finances`.

Comment: Did you tried `Program.joins(:spent_finances).includes(:spent_finances).merge(SpentFinance.where(time_period_type: time_period_type))`?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your **First attempt** as you want to eager load the join, give a try to the following :

```
Program.includes(:spent_finances).where(spent_finances: {time_period_type: time_period_type} ).references(:spent_finances)
```